# closest() method not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent, closest

I've a sample example below, I'm not sure why the first example (using `div`'s) didn't get the text when the second one (using `span`'s) could achieve that with the same JS code using **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**:

```
$('.class-1').closest('div').find('.class-2').text()
```

---

**First snippet (using `div`'s) cant get the text using `closest()`:**

```js
console.log( $('.class-1').closest('div').find('.class-2').text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="class-1">Div 1 Content</div>
  <div class="class-2">Div 2 Content</div>
</div>
```

---

**Second snippet (using `span`'s) getting the text using `closest()`:**

```js
console.log( $('.class-1').closest('div').find('.class-2').text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="class-1">Div 1 Content</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="class-2">Div 2 Content</span>
</div>
```

I know about the alternatives `parents()/parent()/siblings()/nextAll()` that can return the `class-2` text in this case, but I want just to know what occur this behaviour.

Comment: It's because `closest()` includes the current element, therefore `closest('div')` is returning the same element. See http://api.jquery.com/closest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) checks if the calling element fits the selector as well, and in your case `.class-1` is also a `div`.

From the docs:

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that
>   matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up
>   through its ancestors in the DOM tree.