# How to get parent element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want increase the font size of parent element. When i use my code it will increase full body font size how can i avoid that issue? 
Example based on the `id="vs-1"` i want increase the font size of the grant parent li text here 1940 .

```js
$("li #vs-1").parents().css({
  'color': '#ff3600',
  'font-size': '35px'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1940
    <ul>
      <li style="background-color: rgb(255, 54, 0);" id="vs-1"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1970
    <ul>
      <li id="vs-2"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When i use this code it will affect entire body ul li tag . Please give me the solution. Thanks

Comment: `.parent()` is what you're after. Also you have an ID (which should be unique in the DOM btw) so you don't need `li #vs-1` just do `$('#vs-1').parent()`

Comment: Did you try typing your exact title into Google? - your answer is literally the first and second result :)

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right path you should just to specify the parent in `.parents()` call :

```
$('li #vs-1').parents("li").css({'color':'#ff3600','font-size':'35px'});
______________________^^^^
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("li #vs-1").parents('li').css({
  'color': '#ff3600',
  'font-size': '35px'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1940
    <ul>
      <li style="background-color: rgb(255, 54, 0);" id="vs-1"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1970
    <ul>
      <li id="vs-2"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: after 2 minutes needed

Answer (score 2):

Updated: need to reach parent and then use `closest()`. Please check below snnippet

```js
$(function(){
  $("li #vs-1").parent().closest("li").css({'color':'#ff3600','font-size':'35px'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1940
    <ul>
      <li style="background-color: rgb(255, 54, 0);" id="vs-1"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>1970
    <ul>
      <li id="vs-2"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you get any error message in your console when trying this answer

Comment: **4 upvotes fot a non-working answer !!** Sorry but the `closest()` will not work in this situation.. Take a look to **[closest() method not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508008/closest-method-not-working-as-expected)**.

Comment: @Rijo, yes it was not working .. I have corrected my answer , please check

Answer (score 1):

A few things:
To achive what you want, you can use `$('...').parents()[1].css({'...'});`
the `.parents()` method returns an array of all parents, and the first element of the array is the immediate parent.
Also, since you have an id of the element you want to select, you don't have to have li before it.
See the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: ya bro your answer correct only. Can u give me vote for my question

Answer (score 1):

You only want style parent `li`, not that `li` itself. Try this:

```
$("li #vs-1").parent('li').css({
  'color': '#ff3600',
  'font-size': '35px'
});

$("li #vs-1").closest('li').css({
  'color': '#000',
  'font-size': '16px'
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9u9hb839/2/

Comment: ya its working thanks for your work. So my question is valid can u give me vote for my question